# Regular expression not finding both matches

Tags: python, regex

I have this regular expression in Python:

`p = re.compile("<" + tag + ">([aA-zZ0-9\-\s:]*)</" + tag + ">")`

And I cannot seem to get it to find both matches in this string (where tag is 'unique')

`<unique>UNIQUE Passive - Maim:</unique> Basic attacks deal 10 bonus magic damage to monsters on hit.<br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Butcher:</unique> Damage dealt to monsters increased by 10%.<br><br><i>ique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>`

Any ideas why its only matching the first?

Comment: May I ask why you are parsing HTML with regex?

Comment: @Haidro: there is no good answer to that question.

Comment: Are you sure it's matching the first tag, and not everything from the first opening `<unique>` tag to the last closing `</unique>` tag? (Also, regexes can't do general HTML parsing. You can get away with regexes for a few cases, but it'll be fragile.)

Comment: @sberry Well, if it's for practicing regex, then I would understand, really... But then again, it isn't something good which you can practice on

Comment: Its not html.  Its a custom xml with only a fee tags and no attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use p.search, use findall or finditer instead of that.

```python
import re
tag = 'unique'
# p = re.compile("<" + tag + ">([aA-zZ0-9\-\s:]*)</" + tag + ">")
# aA-zZ means a, range A-z and Z. this includes some sign like '[', '^' ... .
# the last '-' in character group( inside [ and ] ) matches '-' self.
p = re.compile("<" + tag + ">([a-zA-Z0-9\s:-]*)</" + tag + ">")

ml = "<unique>UNIQUE Passive - Maim:</unique> Basic attacks deal 10 bonus magic damage to monsters on hit.<br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Butcher:</unique> Damage dealt to monsters increased by 10%.<br><br><i>ique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>"
m = p.search(ml)
print m.group()
print

print p.findall(ml)
print

for m in p.finditer(ml):
    print m.group()
```

output:

```
<unique>UNIQUE Passive - Maim:</unique>

['UNIQUE Passive - Maim:', 'UNIQUE Passive - Butcher:']

<unique>UNIQUE Passive - Maim:</unique>
<unique>UNIQUE Passive - Butcher:</unique>
```

Comment: This is a correct solution, but I ended up finding the mistake in my code that was causing issues.  Turns out there was nothing wrong with my regular expression.